# SuiteCRM Reporting - AOR_Report.js can’t access date parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, suitecrm

I have been looking at a report that has date parameters. Page 1 shows 429 records:

[image]
When going to next set of records there are none:

[image]

Looking at function **changeReportPage** in **AOR_Report.js** it is referring to the date field IDs in this way:

[image]

But the date parameter IDs in the page end with **_date**:

[image]

and consequently always undefined when changeReportPage is called and the result is no records.

A rewrite of the js gets it working but I wondered if I am missing something here.

I am using version 7.10.29